# On cyclic representations of a C*-algebras

Tags: c-star-algebras

I feel the following assertion is true but have no evidence to prove:

There exists an infinite dimensional C*-algebra such any cyclic representation $\pi$ of $A$ is finite dimensional! Probably $\bigoplus_{1}^{\infty}M_2(\mathbb{C})$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one doesn't work.

In fact, if $A$ is any separable infinite-dimensional C$^*$-algebra, then it has a faithful state $\varphi$. If we do GNS for $\varphi$, then $\pi_\varphi$ is a cyclic representation. And it is infinite-dimensional, because $A\subset H_\varphi$ (due to the fact that $\varphi $ is faithful).

Comment: Dear Martin, Thanks for your pay attention. You made an example of an infinite   dimensional C*-algebra which has  an infinite dimensional cyclic representation.  But the question is something else.

Comment: Exactly. So "there exists a C $^*$-algebra with all its cyclic representations finite-dimensional" does not hold. How is this "something else"?

Comment: @AliBagheri Martin is  not  giving an example but  he  is  proving that  every separable infinite  dimensional algebra admits  an infinite  dimensional cyclic  representation. So  your  question has negative  answer if the following statement is true: every $C^*$ algebra can be surjectively maped to a  separable  algebra. Is it a  true  statement?